# Getting values in Jquery Query builder using selectize

Tags: javascript, selectize.js, jquery-query-builder

I'm trying to solve a problem for some days but I can't do it.

This code is using Jquery Query Builder and the plugin selectize, to allow me selecting multiple values.

Everything is okay, except that I could't get the values selected in the input. The screen below shows how the graphic interface works:

[image]

The JS code follows below:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    
        let builder = $('#builder');
    
        const optionsValue = {
            request_type: [
                { value: 'request1', label: 'Request 1' },
                { value: 'request2', label: 'Request 2' },
                { value: 'request3', label: 'Request 3' }
            ],
            priority: [
                { value: 'high', label: 'High' },
                { value: 'medium', label: 'Medium' },
                { value: 'low', label: 'Low' }
            ]
        };
    
        const buildOptions = (result) => {
    
            let options = {};
            let filters = [];
    
            for (let key in result) {
    
                let values = result[key];
    
                for (let key_value in values) {
                    let value = values[key_value];
                    value.optgroup = key;
    
                    value.field = values[key_value].id;
    
                    value.valueSetter = function(rule, val) {
                        rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container input')[0].selectize.setValue(eval("[" + val + "]"));
                    }
    
                    value.valueGetter = function(rule) {
                        return rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container input')[0].selectize.getValue().split(',');
                    }
    
                    value.plugin_config = {
                        valueField: 'value',
                        labelField: 'label',
                        searchField: 'label',
                        sortField: 'label',
                        plugins: ['remove_button'],
                    };
    
                    filters.push(value);
                }
            }
    
            options.allow_empty = { allow_empty: true };
            options.filters = filters;
    
            return options;
        }
    
        const getData = () => {
            return fetch('./request/getdata.php')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
    
                let result = JSON.parse(data);
    
                let options = buildOptions(result);
    
                builder.queryBuilder(options);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        }
    
        const clickSelect = () => {
            $(document).on('change', '.rules-list li .rule-filter-container select', function() {
                let parent = $(this).closest(".rule-container");
                let input_text = parent.find(".rule-value-container input");
    
                let selectedValue = $(this).val();
    
                input_text.selectize({
                    plugins: ["restore_on_backspace", "clear_button", "remove_button"],
                    delimiter: " - ",
                    persist: true,
                    maxItems: null,
                    valueField: "value",
                    labelField: "label",
                    searchField: ["label", "value"],
                    options: optionsValue[selectedValue],
                    allowEmptyOption: true,
                    multiple: true,
                    input: 'selectize'
                });
            });
        }
    
        const getQueryBuilderData = () => {
            $("#qbinfo").on("click", function(){
    
                var rules = builder.queryBuilder('getRules');
    
                console.log(rules);
            });
        }
    
        getData().then(() => {
            clickSelect();
            getQueryBuilderData();
        });
    });
```

When it executes the method **getQueryBuilderData()**, the result is this:

[image]

The field value in the inputs return empty :(

I believe that the problem is in one of these tow methods:

```
        value.valueSetter = function(rule, val) {
            rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container input')[0].selectize.setValue(eval("[" + val + "]"));
        }

        value.valueGetter = function(rule) {
            return rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container input')[0].selectize.getValue().split(',');
        }
```

Because when I use debug, I can't obtain the values from the input, but I am not sure that the problem is here.